# 'Whack someone" vs " Whop someone" vs "Wallop someone"

Tags: differences, verbs

I noticed that, in the dictionary, the words Whack, Whop and Wallop can have a meaning resembling *hit some one hard*. ODO says:

> **Whack (Verb)** = strike forcefully with a sharp blow.
>   **Whop (Verb)** = hit hard.
>   **Wallop (verb)** = strike or hit (someone or something) very hard.

and I'm writing about a boxer or karate fighter who hit his opponent hard in a match. I'm considering saying that the fighter *whacked or whopped or walloped* his opponent.

I would like to know:

(1) Is there a difference between those three? Would you imagine that whacked an opponent is a slightly different meaning than whopped or walloped an opponent? (I typed all these three words into a Google image search, and I got similar images for whopped and walloped. I got different images for whacked. However I cannot grasp a clear difference).

(2) All of those three words have other meanings in dictionary. For example, whop has other meanings like *the regular pulsing sound of a helicopter rotor*

If all these three words are essentially the same meaning, is there any reason I should avoid using one word or the other?

Comment: Why did he "worry"? About what?

Comment: @Kris: I am afraid I didn't understand relevance of this comment.

Comment: Why had "the worrier whacked"?

Comment: @Ramya, I think you used _worrier_ where you want _warrior_. Either way, karate fighter or even karateka would be the usual words.

Comment: Go ahead and use them all... if it is a long match, think of some more words to use for these strikes as well.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, a karate fighter would *strike* or, more specifically, *kick* or *punch*. None of these words seems quite right, but *wallop* is closest. First, *whack* has an additional meaning to [murder](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/whack) (Definition 2), which could cause confusion. The other two words are also fairly informal, and they don't suggest the precision of a karate move. *Whop* is also used for the *sound* of such a blow, which probably isn't a connotation you want. That leaves *wallop*.

Answer (score 0):

*Whacked* can mean to hit with a foot or fist or to hit with a board or a baseball bat, for example, so I wouldn't use that.

*Whopped* feels more colloquial and informal to me than *walloped*, which seems to me more appropriate for a description of a sports encounter.

Still, I'd probably use a different word, something like *slammed, smashed, bashed, battered, beat,* or *trounced*. I think that *walloped* is good, though.